# Is there a list of what Internet Explorer considers in-date for its ActiveX check (specifically, for Java)?

Tags: java, internet-explorer, activex

Internet Explorer now blocks ActiveX controls that it thinks are out of date. At [this blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/proactivesupportEPM/entry/internet_explorers_new_active_x), by Oracle, the initial versions of Java that would be blocked are listed.

Is there a list anywhere which displays the minimum version currently allowed by IE? Is there any way to find this information (specifically, for Java)?

Just upgraded Java on a computer, but it was still blocked. I thought it was the newest version of 7. I can (probably will) try 8, but it would be nice to just look up what version is required.

I will accept an answer that provides a list or method that works right now, but it would be nice if we had a method that will continue to work in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of.  The list that IE uses is [available online](https://iecvlist.microsoft.com/ie11blocklist/1401746408/versionlist.xml), though it's actually an XML file that you'll need to read carefully to get all the gory details.  The file should be valid at least through the lifecycle of IE11.

Details about the ActiveX blocking process (including a then-current list of Java versions) can be found in [this post from the IE team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/08/06/internet-explorer-begins-blocking-out-of-date-activex-controls.aspx).

Note that ActiveX blocking will not apply to the Windows store experience of IE11 (as that version doesn't support ActiveX controls) and may not apply to Spartan (the new version of IE to be made available when Windows 10 ships).
Hope this helps...

-- Lance